# The Next Generation episode where Picard encounters a life form (alien) who speaks in allegories (not Darmok)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I'm looking for a *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode where Picard encounters a life form (alien) who speaks in allegories (not Darmok). Instead of saying humans, he says "Being mostly made of water". This alien is amphibian-like. I remember this creature laughing.

I believe Picard is again alone on a planet with it. Again it is not the Darmok episode.

Comment: The amphibian-like alien laughing is most likely from Darmok

Comment: I was thinking it could also be Armus in "Skin of Evil". It has an evil laugh and at the end of the episode, Picard is alone with it on the planet before he tricks it and beams out.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/902/)

Comment: Was the term they used for us "ugly bags of mostly water"?

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to verify your comments. Thumbs up!

Comment: Sorry people. But this alien looks a lot like the captain of the old starship that  left a log message on the episode: " Booby Trap".  Any clues? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Presumably you're referring to this handsome fellow. https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/7/78/Galek_Sar.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161123015354&path-prefix=en

Comment: I wouldn't call ‘ugly bags of mostly water’ an *allegory* — it's a direct description (albeit a pointedly unfamiliar one), not using symbols or story or metaphor or simile or hidden meaning or anything but literal description.  (Unlike the Tamarians in ‘Darmok’, who spoke only in allegorical reference and allusion.)

Comment: @Valorum  Indeed! I just hope my mind isn't playing trick with me...

Comment: Extending gidds comment, I'd call that an *insult*, not an allegory.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but could it be [Where silence has lease](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode))? The alien, Nagilum, is vaguely amphibian looking and laughs a bit. Picard is not on a planet, but has a scene alone with him. And the alien talks about the Humans' "construction".

Comment: Not Darmok? Then check out the movie *Enemy Mine*.

Comment: *Next Generation episode where Picard encounters an alien who instead of calling them humans, says 'they're mostly made of water'* ?

Answer (score 37):

I think you might have confused two or more episodes. The episode *Home Soil* (s 1, ep17) involves the Enterprise visiting a planet believed to be completely devoid of life, except for a Federation terraforming base. The base has been experiencing mysterious & fatal accidents.

The crew eventually discovers that life *is* present- but not organic life as we know it. The lifeform is silicon-based and refers to humans as "ugly bags of mostly water."

However, this creature is quite small, and definitely not an amphibian, so the episode does not match your visual memory.

Comment: It’s life, Jim, but not as we know it, not as we know it, not as we know it...

Comment: @Broklynite - Man, I think you're star trekkin'! :-)

Comment: Across the universe?

Comment: On the Starship Enterprise under Captain Kirk?

Comment: The creature isn't amphibian in the froglike sense, but it does naturally live in a sort of wet and saline layer in the planet's soil, if I remember correctly, so there's that.

Answer (score 29):

Are you thinking of the crystal microbrain alien they find in ["Home Soil"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Home_Soil_(episode))?

It's the only time in the series that humans are refered to as bags of mostly water as far as I know.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I hope you stay and look around. This answer could be improved by explaining why you think it is the alien from Home Soil. As it stands, a link to Memory Alpha and a YouTube clip make this a link-only answer that causes the questioner to do extra work.

Comment: And also causes the answer to fail later, when the Memory-alpha moves to a new platform that uses different URLs, and Youtube takes down the video in response to a copyright claim by so-and-so.

Comment: Thank you. I've made a quick edit to improve the answer.

Comment: rats, the linked video isn't working for me. I need to hear "ugly bags of mostly water" again!

Comment: rats, the linked video isn't working for me. I need to hear "ugly bags of mostly water" again!  this one might be used instead https://youtu.be/LAlqp0_a0tE

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are talking about [TNG: Skin of Evil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)). The being (Armus) is black slime, refers to us as water, and Picard ends up alone with him briefly.

This was a huge episode back in the day....

Comment: Armus doesn't refer to humans as being made of water. There's a transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/122.htm) if you want to check and/or find the quote you're referring to

Comment: This was a huge episode? I think for most it was hugely disappointing, at least. This episode essentially served a single purpose, which felt entirely forced (because it was), and that purpose wasn't the progression of any character's development. Also, pretty sure this episode isn't what the question is trying to find.

Comment: @Ellesedil - It had high ratings, was extensively trailed and is usually shown as being one of the show's seminal episodes (mostly due to the death of a top billed character). That says "big" to me

Comment: @Ellesedil: "and that purpose wasn't the progression of any character's development" - Well, Tasha progressed into the grave, I suppose.

Comment: @Ellesedil:  One person's "chracter developement" is another person's "boring soap opera."  A good story has something to say.  If it also involves character developement, well, that's nice but not neccessary.

Comment: @Kevin SPOILERS?!?! ;)

Comment: While we're off-topic, it caused tremendous progress in other characters. This is an event that repeatedly comes up in Data's humanity subplot.

Comment: They could have just had a normal episode and thrown Tasha down an elevator shaft like they did with [Dr Pulaski](https://decider.com/2016/03/21/today-in-tv-history-l-a-law-gave-rosalind-shays-the-shaft/)...

Comment: "Save your compassion. It's revolting. You offer it like a prize when in fact it's an insult." "You overrate your gift. **You humans are puny, weak.**" "And still you die from a flake of my power." "You do not understand. I do not serve things evil. I am evil."

Comment: "who speaks in allegories" - see the above. "Being mostly made of water" ? - search transcripts until you find that phrase.

Comment: I did think the blob itself was an interesting concept: unwanted, rejected negative thoughts left behind by beings of intellect.